Does "dar palo" make sense in the following context, something being a drag?
I read a previous post about "dar palo".
I understand what is said about the meaning. Things turning out differently than anticipated or something we hate doing and we are lazy to do it. Can you use it to describe something you dislike?

Este tipo de música me da palo

In English, we can use "that music is a drag" in that sense. It may not be as common. Certainly, we use it more for work or study: "Studying is a drag" or "a real pain".

Not sure if I would use "dar palo" in that context or that I would translate "dar palo" as "being a drag". Don't you have any idiom using the verb "to give" for that context? Something similar to "gives me the chills" but causing you to be lazy or embarrassed. Just to reflect the same structure in both languages: dar/give palo/something.

@RubioRic.Not sure what you mean exactly. Anyeay i think an expression like ,esta música es un rollo, may be better. ??

Yes, here, it is, is a drag. RAE dar palo

loc. verb. coloq. Salir o suceder algo al contrario de como se esperaba o deseaba. The RAE is very useful. Literally, to not be what one expected.


@Lambie. yes, I forgot to check the RAE this time. However, the meaning of something not being what one expected is a little bit at odds with the English sense of something being a drag. In English we may say,''I have to go to work.What a drag!'' That has nothing to do with something not being what we expected. Also, do you think like Quelopande, it can be used for my sentence about music ,for example?

I think that "esta música es un rollo" (It's boring, I don't like it) is better than using "dar palo". The meaning that you can find in the DRAE is not applicable in this context in my opinion.

Using "palo" and "llevar" instead of "dar", you can say: "Estaba deseando ir al concierto, pero vaya palo me llevé, eran horribles, tocaban fatal"

@RubioRic Great, thank you!

Sure, llevar un palo, what a bummer. //Yes, if something is what you didn't expect, it can be a palo.
